# I want to insert my own view or layout inside expandable List view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I need a little help in expandable list view. When the header is clicked, I need to show a list of information, but not in the format of list. I need to use my own view inside like this.

Example Header 1(On click-expands)

```
    Name:
    DOB:
    Nationality:
    Languages Known:
                                 Submit(Button)
```

Header 2 (On click-expands)

```
    Name:
    DOB:
    Nationality:
    Languages Known:
                                 Submit(Button)
```

This is what I want to achieve. Please somebody help. Is there any other way to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own layout. Then it can be set in your adapter class like:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.Your_layout, null);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

For more information follow this link:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/